# Working with csv file in pandas to create a new csv file from old csv file after checking if values of two fields are not zero

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am working on a program where one csv file I am downloading from webpage using pandas

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("file-url")
```

This file has 5 cloumns. I need to check last 2 columns of this file if both values are zero than that line will be eliminated from file. I am new to pandas and python. How to compare two columns and how to write row into a csv file using pandas

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select last 2 rows and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) if both columns has at least one non `0` value by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) :

```
df = pd.read_csv("file-url")

df = df[df.iloc[:, -2:].ne(0).any(axis=1)]
```

Alternative is filter by inverse mask by `~` by test if not both columns has `0` by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df = df[~df.iloc[:, -2:].eq(0).all(axis=1)]
```

Last write to file:

```
df.to_csv('new_file.csv')
```